# Extra legend present

Tags: javascript, d3.js, visualization

I adding two legends to my bar chart but I don't know why there is a extra legend appear. I don't know which part of my code is wrong since I only define two legend in my code.

```
var color_hash = {  0 : ["Male", "blue"],
                    1 : ["Female", "pink"]}

var legend = svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "legend")
            .attr("x", width - 65)
            .attr("y", 25)
            .attr("height", 100)
            .attr("width", 100);

legend.selectAll('g').data(data)
      .enter()
      .append('g')
      .each(function(d, i) {
        var g = d3.select(this);
        g.append("rect")
         .attr("x", width - 65)
         .attr("y", i*25)
         .attr("width", 10)
         .attr("height", 10)
         .style("fill", color_hash[String(i)][1]);
        g.append("text")
         .attr("x", width - 50)
         .attr("y", i * 25 + 8)
         .attr("height", 30)
         .attr("width", 100)
         .style("fill", color_hash[String(i)[1]])
         .text(color_hash[String(i)][0]);

      });
```

the black rectangle is the extra one:

[image]

Comment: Try inspecting the HTML to see the structure of the extra element.  That might hold a clue?  Another idea is to console.log() the data as the legend is being created...is there a data value other than Male or Female (such as null?)?

Comment: @devlincarnate The legend is from the color_hash right? There are only female and male there

Comment: How many items are in the array named `data`?

Answer (score 1):

With the enter/update/exit cycle in D3, you generally want to have a data array that contains one item for every element you want drawn. You have:

- a color has object `color_hash`, *this is what you really want to use to draw the legend*, and
- some data array `data`, though we don't know what is inside of this.

We are using `data` to visualize `color_hash`, this is not ideal.

For one, you only want to plot 2 elements, I can tell you that the length of `data` is at least 3:

You create an empty `g` with:

```
var legend = svg.append("g")
```

Then you select child `g` elements of that:

```
legend.selectAll('g')
```

Since there are none, this is an empty selection. Then you assign data to this selection and enter new HTML/SVG elements:

```
legend.selectAll('g')
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append('g')
```

Since `legend` is an empty selection, the enter selection will create one HTML/SVG element for each item in the data array. After entering (and/or exiting), the number of HTML/SVG elements should be equal to the number of items in the data array. So, `data` must have at least 3 items in it (it could have more *if* additional elements are created, but they fall outside of the SVG/container bounds. This also explains why the third box has no color or text: the color hash has no values with key 2 or greater).

D3 is creates elements from data, generally in a one to one relationship between elements and items. To create our legend, *the data array should be what we want to plot*. As a consequence, we need to convert the color hash to an array:

```
var legendData = [
  {name: "A", color:"crimson"},
  {name: "B", color:"steelblue"}
];
```

Now we just supply that to `selection.data()`

And, since we are now binding the data we want to draw to the legend entries, we can also simplify the code, instead of:

```
 .style("fill", color_hash[String(i)][1]);
```

and

```
 .text(color_hash[String(i)][0]);
```

We can just use:

```
  .style("fill",d.color);
```

and

```
  .text(d.name);
```

This gives us:

```js
var color_hash = {  0 : ["Male", "blue"],
                    1 : ["Female", "pink"]}

var width = 300;
var height = 200;

var svg = d3.select("svg")
  .attr("width",width)
  .attr("height",height);

var legendData = [
  {name:"A",color:"crimson"},
  {name:"B",color:"steelblue"}
]

var legend = svg.append("g")

legend.selectAll('g')
  .data(legendData)
  .enter()
  .append('g')
  .each(function(d, i) {
        var g = d3.select(this);
        g.append("rect")
         .attr("x", width - 65)
         .attr("y", i*25+25)
         .attr("width", 10)
         .attr("height", 10)
         .style("fill", d.color);
        g.append("text")
         .attr("x", width - 50)
         .attr("y", i * 25 + 33)
         .attr("height", 30)
         .attr("width", 100)
         .style("fill", d.color)
         .text(d.name);

      });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

*I'm just focusing on the enter cycle here: there could be further revisions to placement and a different approach to nested appends can offer benefits compared to appending children with .each*

Comment: In my data file, there are four columns, they are year,gender,age and population. In the gender column, there only two kind of value, they are Male and Female, I want to plot the legend based on the gender, Male is blue and female is pink. How can I render the gender column instead of the whole data in the code?

Comment: You need to create a new data array with the two legend items (whether by filtering/mapping/otherwise manipulating the plot's data array, or by creating it by hand as in the answer) - this way .enter will create only two legend entries as selection.enter() is meant to match each row in the data to an html element.